# Time series when the data are averages of different sample sizes

Tags: time-series, stationarity, exponential-smoothing

I am trying to analyse a collection of time series where the observations are averages of different sample sizes. I'm looking at measurements from a high volume system with many users.I get averages every five minutes of the measurements in an ongoing process. There is a strong diurnal effect, with way fewer observations coming in at 3AM than at 8PM, for example. So my time series is not stationary in the variance. It's not really stationary in the mean either.

I would like to apply exponential smoothing to this series to smooth the mean, but I'm not sure if I should make some adjustment for sample size.